# Swift Keypath from String

Tags: swift4, keypaths

Is there a way to create a Keypath from a String in Swift 4 to access a value in a struct by its path or variable name

> Finally I found out that I should use CodingKeys instead of KeyPaths
>   to access the a value of a variable of a struct by String

Thanks in advance,
Michael

Comment: can you add example code on what you are trying to do what to expect ?

Comment: I want to convert a String like 'sensor.temp.1' to a Keypath to access a value in nested strucures. I dont want to hardcode this Keypath to make the path to the value runtime-configurable

Comment: can put example of the struct you have ?

Comment: Just a simple struct, that contains another struct in a variable, that contains the values as Int... Nothing special...

Comment: Check the answer please

Comment: when you say "Finally I found out that I should use CodingKeys instead of KeyPaths to access the a value of a variable of a struct by String" do you have a reference for this? How did you achieve that?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

consider you have something like this,

```
struct foo {

var test: doo

}

struct doo {

var test: Int

}
 //How to use it 

    let doo = Doo(test: 10)
    let foo = Foo(test: doo)

    let mykeyPath = \Foo.test.test

    let result = foo[keyPath: mykeyPath]

    print(result)
```

Comment: Is there I way to get the KeyPath from String to make it runtime-configurable?

Comment: this is how to use keypath with structs so any value changing the keypath accessing remain the same  i don't really understand what you mean by "KeyPath from String to make it runtime-configurable"

Comment: I want to create a KeyPath from String. For example the String contains 'sensors.temperature.temp1' I will get the (Optional) value of the variable in the nested struct with the name 'temp1'

Comment: Coding Keys ? thats something else

Comment: edit your question add the structs and be clear KeyPath, is not Coding Keys , if you are trying to access something with KeyPath thats how thats the correct answer if you want to decode something into another things using structs thats called Coding Keys

Comment: try the code above, in your case  make sure to understand it too

Comment: I haven't heard about CodingKeys and searched for KeyPath instead... I will close this question, because there are already many questions to this thematic out there. Thank you very much for your time answering this senseless question..

Comment: Would you close or delete it?

Comment: i would leave it, other people may find it helpful :) either the answer  or the question, personally i marked as fav